# Issue while formulating regex for the password field

Tags: regex

I am trying to formulate a regexp for a password field, which accepts at least one special character and one alpha numeric character.

I have already tried with this regexp `((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*\W))` on Rubular, which I cooked up. But it's not working properly.

**Test String :** test@123

Kindly suggest a way to overcome this.

If you can please give some explanation as well.

Comment: its sometimes much more readable to break this in to 3 checks rather than one larger regex

Comment: What do you mean exactly when you say its not working properly? It matches your test string perfectly fine.

Comment: I think the OP means that it's not matching the test  string .

Comment: but it does match, even on the website the OP mentioned: http://rubular.com/r/aR9kBLFlrF

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex actually does match your test string. It seems that you are wanting it to be in your capture group though as you wrapped the look-aheads in parenthesis.

Wrapping a capture group around your look-aheads wont capture anything as they are just looking ahead to verify. You'll have to create a capture group capturing the entire thing after like this:

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*\W)(.{6,20})$
```

The `^` and `$` are just checking the entire string passed. The `.` within the capture group `()` is just saying to grab the entire match. The `{6,20}` is saying it has to be between 6 and 20 characters long. You can change the numbers if you want.

[Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/HUDMI3X5Kj)